# runlevels init.d and rc.d

Tags: linux, installation, init, runlevel

I am not sure to ask it here or at serverfault, but it has to do with my script and creating an installer...

I have made a service (linux perl script) and all the configuration files and etc etc.
I would like to make an installer for it so it creates folders/puts files on the right spot, etc.

Now while developing I made a script in the /etc/init.d/ folder called "reliand".

Now when I send all my files, plus the installer to another user and I would copy that file to the same dir on that machine (i know it's same CENTOS) how would I make it run at the right runlevel?

Do I need to make a link in the rd3.d folder? or is there a command to run so it will place itself in the correct runlevels.

Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`chkconfig --add`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chkconfig8.html) and add something like:

```
# chkconfig: 345 20 80
# description: my service
```

to your script in `/etc/init.d`

Oh ... and https://serverfault.com/ is definitely a better place for this question.

Comment: thank you for your answer. exactly what i need. (sorry for posting on the wrong site)